# VB Change Calulator

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a VB 2008 change calculator as an assignment. The program is to use the amount paid - the amount due to calculate the total.(this is working fine). After that, it is to break that amount down into dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. The problem I am having is that sometimes the quantity of pennies, nickels or dimes will be a negative number. For example $2.99 = 3 Dollars and -1 Pennies.

***SOLVED***

Thanks to the responses, here is what I was able to make work with my limited knowledge.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        'Clear boxes

        lblDollarsAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblQuartersAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblDimesAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblNickelsAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblPenniesAmount.Text = String.Empty
        txtOwed.Text = String.Empty
        txtPaid.Text = String.Empty
        lblAmountDue.Text = String.Empty
        txtOwed.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        'Close application' 
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        ' Find Difference between Total Price and Total Received 
        lblAmountDue.Text = Val(txtPaid.Text) - Val(txtOwed.Text)
        Dim intChangeAmount As Integer = lblAmountDue.Text * 100

        'Declare Integers  
        Dim intDollarsBack As Integer
        Dim intQuartersBack As Integer
        Dim intDimesBack As Integer
        Dim intNickelsBack As Integer
        Dim intPenniesBack As Integer

        ' Change Values 
        Const intDollarValue As Integer = 100
        Const intQuarterValue As Integer = 25
        Const intDimeValue As Integer = 10
        Const intNickelValue As Integer = 5
        Const intPennyValue As Integer = 1

        'Dollars 
        intDollarsBack = CInt(Val(intChangeAmount \ intDollarValue))
        intChangeAmount = intChangeAmount - Val(Val(intDollarsBack) * intDollarValue)
        lblDollarsAmount.Text = intDollarsBack.ToString

        'Quarters 
        intQuartersBack = CInt(Val(intChangeAmount \ intQuarterValue))
        intChangeAmount = intChangeAmount - Val(Val(intQuartersBack) * intQuarterValue)
        lblQuartersAmount.Text = intQuartersBack.ToString

        'Dimes 
        intDimesBack = CInt(Val(intChangeAmount \ intDimeValue))
        intChangeAmount = intChangeAmount - Val(Val(intDimesBack) * intDimeValue)
        lblDimesAmount.Text = intDimesBack.ToString

        'Nickels 
        intNickelsBack = CInt(Val(intChangeAmount \ intNickelValue))
        intChangeAmount = intChangeAmount - Val(Val(intNickelsBack) * intNickelValue)
        lblNickelsAmount.Text = intNickelsBack.ToString

        'Pennies 
        intPenniesBack = CInt(Val(intChangeAmount \ intPennyValue))
        intChangeAmount = intChangeAmount - Val(Val(intPenniesBack) * intPennyValue)
        lblPenniesAmount.Text = intPenniesBack.ToString

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A general purpose advice: separate the GUI from the (business) logic. You should create a function that calculates the change for a given *total price* and *total paid*. Since you need to return multiple values (dimes, pennies etc.), you could put them into the fields (properties) of a class.

Comment: Is you teacher suggesting/forcing you to use type as the prefix for variable names? If you don't have then don't. See for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx guidance.

Comment: I agree with Tim Murphy: `intNickelsBack` and `dblChangeAmount` aren't good variable names, but `lblNickelsAmount` is ok.

Comment: I can live with lblNickelsAmount but prefer NickelsAmountLabel and NickelsAmountTextBox, etc.

Comment: Yeah, suffixes look better than prefixes, at least in this case.

Comment: We have to use camelcase (ie. lblDollars). The only thing he did teach us is how he wanted them named. The only things we have learned so far are variables. We haven't learned any if statements, return me, get, demonination unit, or any of that.......I appreciate them, but almost all of the responses are wayyyyy over my head. He said the assignment could be done by creating only 1 variable, and the rest was just simple math.

Comment: Is it to me or `CInt(Val(some integer operation))` could be replaced with `some integer operation`? The same for `Val(integer var)` which could be replaced with `integer var`. Also please change the title to something better, e.g. *VB change calculator (assignment/homework)* or *Change calculator in dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies*.

Comment: Don't edit the solution into your question. Answer your own question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function CalculateChange(ByVal dblDollarsPaid As Double, ByVal dblDollarsOwed As Double)
    Dim intChangeCents As Integer
    Dim change As New Change()

    intChangeCents = CInt((dblDollarsPaid - dblDollarsOwed) * 100)

    change.Dollars = intChangeCents \ 100
    intChangeCents = intChangeCents Mod 100

    change.Quarters = intChangeCents \ 25
    intChangeCents = intChangeCents Mod 25

    change.Dimes = intChangeCents \ 10
    intChangeCents = intChangeCents Mod 10

    change.Nickels = intChangeCents \ 5
    intChangeCents = intChangeCents Mod 5

    change.Pennies = intChangeCents

    Return change
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim c As Change
c = CalculateChange(13.26, 2.99)
Console.WriteLine("{0} dollars, {1} quarters, {2} dimes, {3} nickels and {4} pennies", _
                   c.Dollars, c.Quarters, c.Dimes, c.Nickels, c.Pennies)
```

`\` is the operator for integer division, e.g. 5 \ 2 is 2, not 2.5.

The `Change` structure is from [Alex Essilfie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791654/visual-basic-problem/3799690#3799690).

Comment: Thank you. \ was the solution that I needed.

Comment: By the way, the first result of a Google search for *visual basic .net integer division* is the [answer](http://discuss.techinterview.org/default.asp?dotnet.12.155890.2) to the question. That's how I knew how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example of $2.99, look at where you calculate `inDollarsBack`.  You are obviously getting a value of 3, when you need 2.  Without giving it away, think of possible reasons why dividing 2.99 by 1 would produce a value of 3.

Comment: Thank you,  That makes perfect sense.....it's rounding.  I need to drop the decimal place off......but how do I do that?

Comment: Edit: check out this list of Math functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I figured a way out.....but there must be an easier way.  Posted it at bottom of OP.

Comment: Well, my method worked perfectly when there are coins involved......but now even numbers show -1 quarter and 2 dimes and 5 pennies.....which makes sense why it would because of the way that I wrote it. VB is very new to me. This is my first assignment and my professor is HORRIBLE(he just plays Freecell while we read the book), so I'm really lost.

Comment: Try this function out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=VS.71).aspx
Also, when dealing with money it is sometimes useful to multiply by 100 to get the entire amount in pennies.  Then you don't have to deal with decimals during the math.

Comment: You are referring to the floor/ceiling right? The problem is that we haven't learned about it in class yet and he will say that it is not the correct way to write it.  If I multiply by 100, wouldn't it still round though?

Comment: I appreciate the responses so far, and I'm sure your solutions would work great. However, I'm a complete noob to VB and there has to be a simple, easy way to do this. I am already doing things that we haven't learned in class yet. This is supposed to be an easy assignment and I think I'm making it too complicated........anyone have a VERY simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following change calculator and then update the UI.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class ChangeCalculator

    Private denominations As List(Of Denomination)

    Public Sub New()

        Me.denominations = New List(Of Denomination)

        With Me.denominations

            .Add(New Denomination With {.Value = 1D})
            .Add(New Denomination With {.Value = 0.25D})
            .Add(New Denomination With {.Value = 0.1D})
            .Add(New Denomination With {.Value = 0.05D})
            .Add(New Denomination With {.Value = 0.01D})

        End With

    End Sub

    Public Sub Calculate(ByVal change As Decimal)

        Me.ResetDenominationUnits()

        Dim remainingChange = change

        For Each denomination In (From d In Me.denominations
                                  Order By d.Value Descending
                                 )

            If remainingChange > denomination.Value Then

                denomination.Units = CInt(
                    Conversion.Int(remainingChange / denomination.Value)
                )
                remainingChange -= denomination.Value * denomination.Units

            End If

        Next

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Dollars As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.GetUnits(1D)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Quarters As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.GetUnits(0.25D)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Dimes As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.GetUnits(0.1D)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Nickels As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.GetUnits(0.05D)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Pennies As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.GetUnits(0.01D)
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function GetUnits(ByVal denomination As Decimal) As Integer
        Return (From d In Me.denominations
                Where d.Value = denomination
               ).Single().Units
    End Function

    Private Sub ResetDenominationUnits()

        For Each denomination In Me.denominations
            denomination.Units = 0
        Next

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Denomination

    Public Property Value As Decimal
    Public Property Units As Integer

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Inasmuch as my answer's similar to [Tim Murphy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791654/visual-basic-problem/3798152#3798152), I think this one's more straight forward and you don't need to `update the UI`.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of change or type EXIT to close.")
        Dim input = Console.ReadLine
        Do While input.ToUpper.Trim <> "EXIT"
            Dim c = GetChange(CDec(Val(input)))
            Console.WriteLine("{0} dollars, {1} quarters, {2} dimes, {3} nickels and {4} pennies", _
                              c.Dollars, c.Quarters, c.Dimes, c.Nickels, c.Pennies)

            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Enter the amount of change or type EXIT to quit.")
            input = Console.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Function GetChange(ByVal change As Decimal) As Change
        Dim denominations = New Decimal() {1D, 0.25D, 0.1D, 0.05D, 0.01D}
        Dim c(4) As Integer


        For i = 0 To denominations.Length - 1
            If change >= denominations(i) Then
                c(i) = CInt(Conversion.Int(change / denominations(i)))
                change -= (c(i) * denominations(i))
            End If
        Next

        Dim r As New Change
        With r
            .Dollars = c(0)
            .Quarters = c(1)
            .Dimes = c(2)
            .Nickels = c(3)
            .Pennies = c(4)
        End With

        Return r
    End Function

    Public Structure Change
        Dim _dollars As Integer
        Dim _quarters As Integer
        Dim _nickels As Integer
        Dim _dimes As Integer
        Dim _pennies As Integer

        Public Property Dollars() As Integer
            Get
                Return _dollars
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _dollars = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Quarters() As Integer
            Get
                Return _quarters
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _quarters = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Dimes() As Integer
            Get
                Return _dimes
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _dimes = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Nickels() As Integer
            Get
                Return _nickels
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _nickels = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Pennies() As Integer
            Get
                Return _pennies
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _pennies = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Structure

End Module
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, I don't understand your point of not needing to update the UI. You are updating the UI with calls to Console.WriteLine().

Answer (score 0):

Quite Simply, here it is. To solve the negative change, remove all Options except Explicit

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class frmMoneyChange
    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        lblFivesAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblTensAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblDollarsAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblQuartersAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblDimesAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblNickelsAmount.Text = String.Empty
        lblPenniesAmount.Text = String.Empty
        txtOwed.Text = String.Empty
        txtPaid.Text = String.Empty
        lblAmountDue.Text = String.Empty
        txtOwed.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click


        Dim decChangeAmount As Decimal
        Dim intDollarsBack As Integer
        Dim intQuartersBack As Integer
        Dim intDimesBack As Integer
        Dim intNickelsBack As Integer
        Dim intPenniesBack As Integer
        Dim decPaid As Decimal
        Dim decOwed As Decimal

        Const intFiveDollarValue As Integer = 5
        Const intTenDollarValue As Integer = 10
        Const intDollarValue As Integer = 1
        Const decQuarterValue As Decimal = 0.25
        Const decDimeValue As Decimal = 0.1
        Const decNickelValue As Decimal = 0.05
        Const decPennyValue As Decimal = 0.01



        decOwed = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOwed.Text)
        decPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPaid.Text)
        decChangeAmount = decPaid - decOwed
        lblAmountDue.Text = decChangeAmount.ToString("C")

        'Ten Dollars
        intDollarsBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ intTenDollarValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intDollarsBack) * intTenDollarValue
        lblTensAmount.Text = intDollarsBack.ToString

        'Five Dollars
        intDollarsBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ intFiveDollarValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intDollarsBack) * intFiveDollarValue
        lblFivesAmount.Text = intDollarsBack.ToString

        'Dollars 
        intDollarsBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ intDollarValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intDollarsBack) * intDollarValue
        lblDollarsAmount.Text = intDollarsBack.ToString

        'Quarters 
        intQuartersBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ decQuarterValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intQuartersBack) * decQuarterValue
        lblQuartersAmount.Text = intQuartersBack.ToString()

        'Dimes 
        intDimesBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ decDimeValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intDimesBack) * decDimeValue
        lblDimesAmount.Text = intDimesBack.ToString

        'Nickels 
        intNickelsBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ decNickelValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intNickelsBack) * decNickelValue
        lblNickelsAmount.Text = intNickelsBack.ToString

        'Pennies 
        intPenniesBack = (decChangeAmount * 100 \ decPennyValue * 100)
        decChangeAmount = decChangeAmount - (intPenniesBack) * decPennyValue
        lblPenniesAmount.Text = intPenniesBack.ToString

    End Sub

End Class
```