# Penny calculator mod division

Tags: vb.net

I have an assignment for a beginners VB class, and I have looked for examples for a penny calculator and have read them and tried to figure out where I am going wrong. I have a text box that takes the number of pennies you want to figure out. If you input 101 pennies it comes back with 1 dollar and 1 penny.

Strangely it works for up to 137 pennies. That comes back with 1 dollar 1 quarter 1 dime 2 pennies. If it goes to 138 or higher it just screws up. If I input 138 I get 1 dollar, 2 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, 3 pennies. If I use 17 I get 1 quarter, 2 dimes, 1 nickel, 2 pennies.

Here is the arithmetic portion of my code.

```
    DolBack = intLeftOver / 100
    intLeftOver = intLeftOver Mod 100
    LblDolRes.Text = DolBack.ToString

    QrtBack = intLeftOver / 25
    intLeftOver = intLeftOver Mod 25
    LblQrtRes.Text = QrtBack.ToString

    DimBack = intLeftOver / 10
    intLeftOver = intLeftOver Mod 10
    LblDimRes.Text = DimBack.ToString

    NicBack = intLeftOver / 5
    intLeftOver = intLeftOver Mod 5
    LblNicRes.Text = NicBack.ToString

    PenBack = intLeftOver
    LblPenRes.Text = PenBack.ToString
```

I have tried to look my code over and look at other examples, but apparently I'm doing it a little differently. If anyone could point out the apparent major flaw in my code or my way of doing it I would appreciate it.

Further clarifying I have looked at the post at
[Penny Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791654/vb-change-calulator)
Obviously there are a few differences with the actual arithmetic. In the link given is that because that is the only way to do it without rounding issues?

there are 100 pennies in a dollar, 25 pennies in a quarter, 10 pennies in a dime, 5 pennies in a nickel.

EDIT: Thanks for the help and pointing out my error. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it's a rounding error.  Use

```
DolBack = intLeftOver \ 100
```

instead of

```
DolBack = intLeftOver / 100
```

(and the same for the other ones) and you'll see a very different result.

The reason is that the `/` operator will do floating point division, regardless of the values either side of it, so `38/25` will yield an answer of 1.52, which rounds upwards (as you suspected) when assigned back to the variable, which is defined as an Integer.  On the other hand, the `\` operator will do integer division, truncating rather than rounding.

Comment: sigh.... I have a paper with notes that even sorta points that out. I thought I WAS using the one that dropped the remainder. Thank you for pointing out my stupidity.... although I am happy it seems to work otherwise.

Comment: @user3534276 its called `integer division`.  be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer since it worked

Answer (score 1):

The Math.DivRem method is helpful for this kind of problem.

```
    Dim dollars As Integer
    Dim fifty As Integer
    Dim quarter As Integer
    Dim dime As Integer
    Dim nickel As Integer
    Dim pennies As Integer = 137

    dollars = Math.DivRem(pennies, 100, pennies)
    fifty = Math.DivRem(pennies, 50, pennies)
    quarter = Math.DivRem(pennies, 25, pennies)
    dime = Math.DivRem(pennies, 10, pennies)
    nickel = Math.DivRem(pennies, 5, pennies)
```